# validate coordinate using regex

Tags: regex

I want to validate column in oracle database of type `NUMBER(5,2)` using regex, I have tried but it not work correctly as required manner, this restricted validation needed in regex:

REGEX: 
`[-+]?\\d{0,3}\\.?\\d{0,2}+`

1. 999 valid
2. 9999 invalid
3. -999.99 valid
4. -999. invalid
5. 999.9 valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected for the cases you've provided:

```
^[-+]?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

If you have problems with it, let me know what cases it fails on (and if possible a worded description of what should be matched)

Comment: I am not sure but I think there are max 2 digits after the decimal separator => `{1,2}`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - yes of course, silly me. Corrected. Thanks for pointing it out